# End of statement expected while using Dot Format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print the following of code :

```
print('hello "my friend '{}' "'.format(name))
```

such that the output is:

```
'hello "my friend 'ABCD' " '
```

But I get the error: `End of Statement expected`

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape quotes if you want to use them in a string:

```py
print('hello "my friend \'{}\'"'.format(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
print("""hello "my friend '{}' " """.format(name))
```